# How to get the last executed command in IDLE as in R?

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

When I use R and execute a command in the command window, I can just press up and I get the last executed command in the current command line. What key do I need to press in order to get the same in Python?

Edit: When I asked this question, I did not know what IDLE or iPython is. I just googled "download python" and downloaded it. But now I know I am using IDLE.

Comment: install `ipython` and use that

Comment: completely depends in what you are using, ipython idle  etc..

Comment: Why did I get a downvote for my question. What was so wrong about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in IDLE, use Alt+P and Alt+N to navigate your command history.

Comment: It's working, thanks. However, I don't like that it seems it's not possible to do it with just clicking one key.

Comment: @stats_guy You can customize IDLE's keyboard shortcuts. Go to Options > Configure IDLE > Keys, and change the bindings for history-next and history-previous.

Comment: @senshin Thank you senshin. So, I found what I wanted. Nice!

Comment: Configure up arrow key for history->previous, that way, the hardwired behavior in you would be mapped here

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who comes upon this looking for a mac solution, I found that <kbd>Contrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Contrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> worked to cycle through previously executed lines in IDLE (Python) 2.7.10 on OS 10.8.5.

I realize that this should work without the <kbd>Option</kbd>, but for months I needed to use both modifier keys to execute the shortcut properly.